# Python 2, raw_input in define function. Returning value

Tags: python-2.x

I decided to have a little bit fun with coding python 2 in a long while and decided to try make somewhat playable game of Go.

I quickly tumbled on this issue while trying to make function for the game, it seems like I'm not understanding how raw_input or functions work fundamentally. I cut the part of the code that is giving me the trouble here. When I try to run this, I can get to give inputs, but after that I get NameError: name 'crd_x' is not defined, in the stoneplacement line. The code does work without using the function, but when I try to clean it up like this, I get the said error.

What exactly does return crd give out and how I'm actually supposed to give out variables from def functions?

```
def checkplayerinput():
    if player_on_turn == 0:
        crd = raw_input("Place Black stone (X-Y): ").split("-")
    elif player_on_turn == 1:
        crd = raw_input("Place White stone (X-Y): ").split("-")
    crd_x = int(crd[1])
    crd_y = int(crd[0])
    return crd_x, crd_y

def stoneplacement(crd_x, crd_y, player_on_turn):
    if board[crd_x][crd_y] == "+" and player_on_turn == 0:
        board[crd_x][crd_y] = "B"
    elif board[crd_x][crd_y] == "+" and player_on_turn == 1:
        board[crd_x][crd_y] = "W"

stop = 0
while stop == 0:
    #User input and derive coordinates
    checkplayerinput()

    # Stone placement
    stoneplacement(crd_x, crd_y, player_on_turn)
```

edit. just switched the place of crd_x and crd_y like they are in the actual code. It produces exact same NameError however.

Comment: Can you add the traceback?

Answer (score 0):

So crd is going to give you an array of strings based on whatever the user types in, separated by the ‘-‘ symbols. For example if player_on_turn == 0, and you entered for example “X-Y” (whatever your game calls for), checkplayerinput() would return crd as [“X”, “Y”].

Also, remember that an array is indexed starting at 0.  So in this example, crd[0] == “X”.

Running through your code, does that explain why your stoneplacement() function throws a NameError? I.e. are you inputting the right raw_input to yield crd[1]?

Also, did you define crd before def checkplayerinput() in the code?  According to python scope rules, if you define the variable crd inside of the function, it will not have a global value outside of it (and will throw an error if you reference it in another function).  This is likely why you are able to run your code without the function definitions.  Try adding a line “global crd” or “crd = [ ]” somewhere outside of the function and it will allow you to access crd in the stoneplacement(( function.

Comment: That's how understood it myself. What's the strange part is that the code works fine as it is, if I don't use the def function, but when I try to return the values from function checkplayerinput() the other function stoneplacement() doesn't accept them. That's why I got confused.

Originally I changed values from crd to crd_x and crd_y integers inside the function and returned those values, but it gave the same error. I apparently changed it trying to figure out why it does not work in this post.

Comment: Ahhh, saw your edit. I thought return would give out global variables, even if variables were defined locally. I went ahead and initialized crd_x and crd_y before the function and handled them as global variables inside the function and it works now. I did however read that it isn't recommended to handle variables inside the functions as 'global variable'?